# Can someone show me how I can debug this html form/javascript combination?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm experimenting with the Google Maps API, and am trying to do a barebones directions app. The form calls the calcRoute() function, which, using alerts, I can see *does* have the correct 'start' and 'end' variables defined. However, the page is simply reloaded with the form cleared and the map unchanged. For the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong. Does anybody see anything glaring/what might be causing the problem? Thanks!

Also, apparently I suck at stackoverflow markdown, so here's a pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/BMThntPz

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Google Maps script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" <google maps api> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var directionDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var philadelphia = new google.maps.LatLng(39.9522, -75.1642);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: philadelphia,
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      }

      function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;     
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div class="container" style="height: 100%">
      <div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return calcRoute()">
          <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="start">
          <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="end">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Let's go!">
      </form> <!-- /trip info -->
    </div> 

    <div>
      <div id="map_canvas" ></div>
    </div> 

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have Firebug (Firefox) or Chrome developer tools enabled?  If you have not used these tools, it is well worth your while to learn them (they're pretty easy to learn).

Answer (score 0):

There's a great screencast that shows how to debug the Maps API using Chrome Developer Tools:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb4gvrNrDWw&feature=player_embedded